# Is celebrating independence day in accordance to Islam?

Tags: islamic-government, fatwa-explanation, ummah

Assalam o Alaikum to all my Muslim brothers,

Darul uloom Deoband issued fatwa and instructed all madrasas to celebrate the independence day of the country.

Now, I'm just a student of knowledge so I can't say anything with conviction but From what I understand Nationalism (assabhiyah) was discouraged by the Holy Prophet Muhammed (saw).

Therefore is celebrating independence day along side the kuffar, by hoisting flags and singing national anthems tolerated in Islam or is it Against Islam?

Also why has the ummah become so intoxicated with nationalism in the past century? Sadly, it seems The young these days are ready to fight their Muslims brothers openly in defense of their nations and government.

Answer (score 2):

According to the law of Islam, it is completely prohibited to celebrate Independence Day, not only that, but other ceremonies too as per the The Messenger of Allah -peace and prayer of Allah be upon him- said,
إن لكل قوم عيدا ، وهذا عيدنا
“Every nation has its own ‘Id, and ‘Id al Fithr is our ‘Id (the muslims). (Narrated by Bukhari, no. 952, 3931, and Muslim no. 892)

Read more at: [**whatisquran.com**](https://whatisquran.com/992-what-is-the-ruling-of-celebrating-the-independence-day.html)

Answer (score 0):

Translation of Indian national anthem by [Tagor itself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jana_Gana_Mana):

```
Thou art, the ruler of our minds, of all people
The dispenser of India's destiny!
Thy name rouses the heart of Punjab, Sindh, Gujarat
and Maratha, of the Dravida and Odisha
and Bengal; It echoes in the hills of Vindhya and the 
Himalayas, and mingles in the music of Ganga and Yamuna
and is chanted by the waves of the Indian sea.
They pray for thy blessings and sing thy praise.
The saving of all people waits in thy hands,
Thou dispenser of India's destiny.
Victory, Victory, Victory to thee.[14]
```

There are many words which Islam doesn't allow.

Of course we can celebrate the freedom of country in the limit of Islamic rules. All the Madarsa in India they celebrate Independence day with chanting of "Sare Jahan se achha...."

[Sahih al-Bukhari Narrated Abu Umama:](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/56/122)

> Some people conquered many countries and their swords were decorated
>   neither with gold nor silver, but they were decorated with leather,
>   lead and iron.

In Islam, nationalism or tribalism is disliked but not outright haram. at the smae time self defense is certainly lawful.